# Finding the interval with the highest summed count?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

Given a set of entries, each containing a time index and a int count value,
ie
class Entry
{
    time:int
    count:int
}

write a function that will give the time interval with the highest count together,

ie,
if we had entries

```
100, 2
100, 1
110, 10
200, 4
1000, 3
1200, 8
```

and we ran something like

```
int highestInterval(int interval_range)
highestInterval( 50 )
```

it would return 100, because in 100-150, you have counts 2, 1, and 10.

I managed to get a O(n^2) solution for it, but I think theres a better solution. I think it might have to do with some preprocessing of the interval buckets, but I can't figure out the solution.

Comment: Simple loop O(n) for this i believe. I wont post code as it seems to be howework =)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you made it already using two for loops so it is a mere question of improvement.

Here goes one possible solution:

CODE:

```
raw_data=[100,2;
100,1;
110,10;
200,4;
1000,3;
1200,8];
[max_val,indx]=max(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(A) sum(raw_data(abs(raw_data(A,1)-raw_data(:,1))<50,2)),1:size(raw_data,1),'UniformOutput',false)));
raw_data(indx,1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
ans =

   100
```